# how to handle the file error?

Tags: iphone

I am getting a file error when i am trying to write a string into a file:

```
 NSFileManager *filemgr;

    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];
    NSString *docFile = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
  if ([file fileExistsAtPath: docFile] == YES)
    {    if(![formatedlogStr writeToFile:LOG_FILE_V1  atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error])
            {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error userInfo]);
            }

        }
```

this gives me an error :

```
Error: {
    NSFilePath = "error_log_V1.txt";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. Permission denied\"";
    NSUserStringVariant = Folder;
```

How to solve the problem I don't know. 
Can anybody help me?

Comment: The pasted error contains "Permission denied" string in it, maybe you are trying to write to a folder where you do not have write permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correctly finding a path within your documents directory, but you are trying to log the information to a bare path.  You should follow the same procedure to build a path to a file within your sandbox for the log file and use that instead of `LOG_FILE_V1`.

Comment: could you help by giving a example ...?

Comment: Your own code is an example.  Your own code correctly builds a path to a file in your sandbox.  You should use that same technique to build a path for your log file.